# Delegated authentication in a developer org

Tags: delegated-authentication, support

I'd like to test if I could build a multi factor authentication solution using a device not supported by force.com. I think using delegated authentication is the right way to solve this. However I would prefer to do this development in my developer account.

To enable delegated authentication a ticket needs to be raised with Salesforce support to enable the feature. However I cannot seem to create a case from by developer instance. If I watch the URL "NO_ACCESS" flashes by while trying to login to the support portal. I've tried multiple DE instances with the same result. I suspect that Salesforce is not offering support for the DE instances and thus I won't be able to turn on the requested feature.

Am I correct or should I use a different approach to have the feature enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this feature enabled in DE orgs. You need to find a way to submit a support ticket. I was able to do this using my regular account in our performance edition org.